# Mysql query with 'n' number of conditions enclosed with NOT

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to build Mysql where clause from the user's input.

ex:
if the user enters `EmpId > 10 AND Dept = "Prod"` then the where clause will be

```
SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE EmpId > 10 AND Dept = 'Prod'
```

what if the user enters like

```
NOT(EmpId > 10 AND Dept = "Prod")
```

and there may be n number of conditions can be added into NOT() condition.

What would be better approach to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Not with you , it's up to the user to provide syntactically and logically correct code , mysql will take care of the syntax checking but syntactically correct code does not guarantee a correct outcome.

Comment: (1) I don't see a question in this question.  (2) Putting user input into queries like this is **very** dangerous, exposing the code both to SQL injection and hard-to-debug syntax errors.  I might suggest that you consider some other alternative.

Comment: Hi Gordon, our parsing engine will do the validation for each user entered fields (like EmpId, Dept). After the validation, need to build the mysql where clause.